# Projective representation of restricted indefinite orthogonal group $SO^+(p,q)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, fundamental-groups

For the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3)$, all of its projective representations are of the form
\begin{equation}
D(\Lambda_1)D(\Lambda_2) = \pm D(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)
\end{equation}

As far as I know, this is because the fundamental group of $SO^+(1,3)$ is $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

How would we generalize this to the case of the restricted indefinite orthogonal group $SO^+(p,q)$? That is, for the projective representations
\begin{equation}
D(\Lambda_1)D(\Lambda_2) = c_{\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2}D(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)
\end{equation}

what values can $c_{\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2}$ take?

What I'm guessing is that it is somehow dependent on the fundamental group of $SO^+(p,q)$. So, as the fundamental group of $SO^+(p,q)$ [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group#Topology)
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\pi_1(SO^+(p,q)) & p = 0 & p = 1 & p = 2 & p\ge 3 \\
\hline
q = 0 & 1 & 1 & \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z_2} \\
\hline
q = 1 & 1 & 1 & \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z_2} \\
\hline
q = 2 & \mathbb{Z}& \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z} \\
\hline
q \ge 3 & \mathbb{Z_2} & \mathbb{Z_2} & \mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2} \\
\hline
\end{array}

As $SO^+(p,1)$ and $SO^+(p,0)$ also have $\mathbb{Z_2}$ as its fundamental group for $p\ge 3$, I expect $c_{\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2} = \pm 1$ for these. But, I have no idea how to prove this. Also, I have no idea what $c_{\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2}$ can be for the other values of $SO^+(p,q)$, nor how to go about proving this. So, how does one determine values of $c_{\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2}$ for these cases?

Comment: I think a projective (unitary) representation would be such that the $c$'s could take any value in $G$ where $G \subset U(1)$ is a subgroup isomorphic to a quotient of the fundamental group $\pi_1(SO^+(p,q))$. (Also I'm not sure the $c$'s depend only on the $\Lambda$'s, they probably also depend on some choice of path, which lifts uniquely to the universal covering group of $SO^+(p,q)$.)